# Previous scene lingering in the background Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been trying to switch from the main menu for our game into the first level. But the main menu keeps showing in the background no matter what I try.

So, this is our main menu (the loading screen looks just about identical, but with a loading bar in the center and without the buttons or SOMNIUM):

*Yes, I know it looks ridiculous. This was a stand-in that one of our artists did in ten minutes in paint. They're still working on the real main menu art.*

[image]

And this is what I get when I try to start a new game (you can see how the loading canvas from the main menu scene is still there in the background):
[image]

I got the code I'm currently using from a tutorial (I hoped copying their code would help - it didn't, but it looks nicer than mine).

```
public class StartGame : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject mainMenuCanvas;
    public GameObject loadingScreenCanvas;
    public Slider slider;

    
    public void NewGame(int levelToLoad) 
    {
        StartCoroutine(LoadAsynchronously(levelToLoad));
    }

    IEnumerator LoadAsynchronously(int levelToLoad)
    {
        // Set the loading of the level as an async operation
        AsyncOperation operation = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(levelToLoad, LoadSceneMode.Single);

        while(!operation.isDone)
        {
            // Get the 0-1 progress value
            float progress = Mathf.Clamp01(operation.progress / 0.9f);
            
            // Apply the progress value to the slider, which also goes from 0-1
            slider.value = progress;

            // Going to have a thing here to show the percentage completed as text

            // End the Coroutine
            yield return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Other than specifying LoadSceneMode.Single, I've trying directly destroying the main menu scene when moving to the game scene. But that had no effect. I've also trying turning off the canvas for the main menu scene when moving to the game scene. But that didn't work either.

Comment: Just create a new camera in the game scene.

Comment: @shingo It already has a Main Camera object. Is there a way for me to manually switch to using it?

Comment: I don't know how do you setup it, so you might create a new one, then copy the properties. The existed camera didn't render the whole screen, so these areas kept their states.

Comment: `But that had no effect` and `But that didn't work either` are too vague to be helpful - what code exactly did you try?

Answer (score 0):

Before loading the new scene, you can get a handle to the current scene with `SceneManager.GetActiveScene`. Then when the new scene has finished loading, you can manually unload the old scene with `SceneManager.UnloadSceneAsync`.